# Cannot resolve ILogger<T> Simple Injector ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector, serilog

We use Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core application. Recently we've decided to use Serilog for logging purposes.

Configuration was done in Program.cs as stated in their [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore). Then, in order to make Simple Injector able to resolve `ILoggerFactory` I did something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseMvc();

    // As per my understanding, we force SimpleInjector to use 
    // ILoggerFactory registration from IApplicationBuilder
    container.CrossWire<ILoggerFactory>(app)
}
```

After that `ILoggerFactory` can be injected wherever we use it. And it works fine (creates new instances `ILogger<T>`).

But this is annoying, to create instance from factory every time we need. 
It would be better to get `ILogger<T>` directly in dependent class, instead of `ILoggerFactory`.

So, how can I register `ILogger<T>` to get instance in case like below?

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    public HelloWorldController(ILogger<HelloWorldController> logger)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Alsami's answer would work, use the following registration instead:

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ILogger),
    c => typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);

// This next call is not required if you are already calling AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents
container.CrossWire<ILoggerFactory>(app);
```

This exact example is shown in the [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=registerconditional#context-based-injection).

This registration allows injecting the `Logger<T>` into a *non-generic* `ILogger` constructor argument, where the `T` of `Logger<T>` becomes the type the logger is injected into. In other words, when `HelloWorldController` depends on `ILogger`, it will get injected with a `Logger<HelloWorldController>`. This means you can simplify your `HelloWorldController` to the following:

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    public HelloWorldController(ILogger logger)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

By letting your application components depend on `ILogger` rather than `ILogger<T>` you:

- Simplify your application code
- Simplify your unit tests
- Remove the possibility of making accidental errors, because it becomes impossible to inject the wrong logger.

Comment: It is a bad idea to register the logger as singleton just because the creation of the logger is heavy and you have to pass a type, that ieven has a purpose and should be passed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8485625/5397642

Comment: `Logger<T>` is thread-safe and can be safely registered as singleton. As a matter of fact, ASP.NET Core itself registers it as singleton.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to register the logger iteself as a generic type.
I don't know simple injector but this should be the correct syntax.

```
container.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: Oh God! It couldn't be simpler. You are lifesaver! Works as expected. Thank you!